# Getting keys of an associative array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have heard that JavaScript does not support associative arrays. Is it true?

I mean:

```
assocArray = [
  {a: ""},
  {b: ""},
  {c: ""}
];
```

How do I get the keys of the above `assocArray`?

I tried using:

```
for (each in assocArray) {}
```

But it gives: 0, 1, 2

Comment: `assocArray.map(item => Object.keys(item)[0])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with [**`flatMap()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

> The `flatMap()` method first maps each element using a mapping function, then ***flattens*** the result into a new array. It is identical to a `map()` followed by a `flat()` of depth 1, but `flatMap()` is often quite useful, as merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.

and [**`Object.keys()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

```js
var assocArray = [{a : "" },{b : ""},{c : ""}]; 
var keys = assocArray.flatMap(i => Object.keys(i));
console.log(keys);
```

Comment: `map + flat` = [flatmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `spread` operator and the `Object.keys` method:

```js
let assocArray = [{a : "" },{b : ""},{c : ""}];

let oneObject = Object.assign({}, ...assocArray);
let keys = Object.keys(oneObject);

console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through the objects of your array, you can use the following.

```
for(index in assocArray){
    assocArray[index]
}
```

But, I have the feeling that you should use a dictionary:

```
assocArray = {a : "" , b : "" , c : "" };
```

And then, loop through it

```
for (var key in assocArray) {

    // Skip loop if the property is from prototype
    if (!assocArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    var obj = assocArray[key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
assocArray = [{a : "" }, {b : ""}, {c : ""}];

for(each in assocArray){
  console.log(each); // Each is actually the index
  console.log(assocArray[each]); // The item at index 'each'
  console.log(Object.keys(assocArray[each])[0]); // The first of the keys of the object at index 'each'
}
```